# Retrieve data from MySQL database by using Android QR Scanner

Tags: java, android, mysql, qr-code

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. I'm a beginner in android and currently developing an app that uses a QR Scanner. The process is as below.

1. There're several objects with QR codes attached
2. App scans one QR code
3. Get the data retrieved related to that specific object (ex: name of the object, description of the object, images) from a remote MySQL database
4. Show the data in the app

So this is the simple process of the app. I do not know any technologies that I can use to achieve this since I'm a beginner. I would be obliged if someone could explain how I can do this.

**Edit** : This is different from directly calling data from MySQL database since it involves a QR code scanning part also. I can get the data from MySQL database and show it in android. But the complex part is how to get data automatically shown in the app after scanning the QR code. I have integrated Zxing QR Scanner.

Thank you.

Comment: Android has only sqlite, no mysql. If you have hosted mysql in some online Server, then you need to develop an API for extracting the mySQL data from that Server. API can be developed with any server languages like php.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry if it was unclear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, there are 2 main tasks you have to accomplish:

1. Scan QR code.
2. Retrieve info from a web service (which is backed by MySQL).

For (i), you would use popular QR Scanner libraries such as [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/). Using such libraries would require you to write some extra custom classes, just follow their instruction.

For (ii), you would use a networking library such as [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), Volley, ... to get data from the web service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I use volley, how can I connect it with Zxing to call the database and get the data?

Comment: According to your edited question, there's no need for networking library anymore, so you can forget Volley. When integrating ZXing, the QR code result would be provided in a callback function (you can read ZXing example for that). In that function, you should execute the task to retrieve data with the QR code string from MySQL server. Remember to do such task in background (using AsyncTask for example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any own research before asking here?

Nevertheless you can achieve your solution by trying out these steps:

1.) You need an API to scan your QR Code. By searching via Google i instantly found this page: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162 Here you can implement a barcode reader (but it also is able to read QC Codes as I understand)

2.) You need to find out which content the QR codes includes (e.g. an unique ID or something like that so you can identify your article)

3.) You need a database (e.g. you could use Apache Tomcat which includes a mySql database) where these IDs are stored.

4.) Your android app has to communicate with the server/database with e.g. webservices (you can google it, you will find some ways to implement webservices)

Still I can't you price "the" solution. You have to use google, read different tutorials and find out how you can solve your problem. If you are expecting difficulties you can still ask here.

I hope I still could help you a little.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I combed the internet looking for an answer. But this was the last thing I could do (posting it in stackoverflow) expecting some expert knowledge. I have edited the question a bit. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: So you already have the QC scanning part and the database part? So you only need to check my Nr.2. When you scan the QR Code you get an URL or any text out of it. You could use these information or any part of it to have a uniquie identifier. So if you use the same identifier in your database you can retrieve the datasets from the database using this ID from your QR Code and a simple SQL statement / webService. Is it clear what I mean or where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: So, once I get the unique identifier from the QR code, I need to use a SQL query to call the database through the webservice?